# Вызвать метод при клике на TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Знатоки, прошу помочь в таком вопросе:  Есть TabControl с 4-мя элементами. При загрузке формы они грузятся все разом. Как я могу сделать загрузку какого либо TabItem'а только когда кликну на него(метод уже готов, нужно его просто вызвать при клике). (Перерыла весь интернет, ничего не подошло)  На данный момент на всех 4-х TabItem'ах стоит `Loaded="realm1(2,3,4)_Loaded"` В итоге грузятся все.

Comment: Задача состоит только в том, чтобы при выборе итема вызвать произвольный метод с возможностью определить, какой по порядку итем был кликнут?

Comment: При клике на итем просто вызвать метод :)

Comment: А зачем вам? Вы не используете MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

Выбор вкладки в `TabControl` - это фактически выбор (select) элемента из списка.

Xaml:

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
...
</TabControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Обработка
}
```

При этом, первоначальное открытие итема так же будет сопровождаться событием `SelectionChanged`.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую

Comment: К сожалению это не подошло ( у меня на каждой вкладке есть методы, подгружающие информацию по содержанию, а грузиться должны только если на вкладку кликнули. По итогу программа все равно грузит все вкладки разом

Comment: Вам нужно при клике по вкладке программно подгрузить всё содержимое этой вкладки? Почему не сделать это в обработчике `SelectionChanged`, вытащив информацию о нажатой вкладке и проверив какой-нибудь свой флаг, была ли эта вкладка уже загружена?

Comment: Я не опытна в этих делах ( каждая вкладка у меня грузит отдельный контент, как определить какая нажата? или определенить нажатие ее и подгрузить контент?

Comment: Для каждой вкладки у меня имется свои методы - 4 вкладки и 4 метода, не хочу, чтобы они загружались, как только загружена программа

Comment: Вы загружаете содержимое во вкладки из кода? Вкладки изначально пустые?

Comment: нет, вкладки содержат элементы, которые подгружаются через методы, именно эти методы я хочу включить на подгрузку

Comment: Извините, но мне не удаётся вас понять :) Вкладки либо изначально содержат элементы в xaml, либо вкладки пустые и вы вызываете метод, который создает элемент в коде и вставляет этот элемент во вкладку. Возможно, если вы предоставите xaml и код, станет более понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Разметка xaml в каждой из вкладок, так же в каждой из вкладок есть модули, которые подгружают информацию, каждая вкладка с модулем подгружает инфу из разных таблиц в базе.

Answer (score 0):

не знаю, актуален ли еще ответ. Я для подобной цели использую TabRests_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) и LostFocus. TabRests -имя моей вкладки